# Enlarge button of graph of WAF ACL created using AWS cloudwatch dashboard not working when loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to load an WAS WAF Acl graph inside my application(react JS) using IFrame. For that I have created a dashboard using cloudwatch service of AWS and through which I got the Link(publicly shared) of the Dashboard for ACL graph. I am loading that Link into the application using IFrame. My concern is that there is an enlarge icon which is used to display graph onto whole screen of the user but that button is not working when I am loading that dashboard inside IFrame and working when loading the graph directly into a new tab.
Can anyone provide me a solution which I can apply so that enlarge button start working inside IFrame too.
Attaching screenshot of the section of the dashboard containing that enlarge button for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrfjH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.